# cross browser text flow within div

Tags: html, css

How do you have some text flowing within a `div` that does not break words up? I can achieve this is Safari and Chrome but not on MS IE or Firefox.

Safari/Chrome output example:

> An emergency lighting survey to be conducted. The emergency lighting system
>   is to inspected by a competent electrical engineer and any recommendations 
>   following such an inspection are to be implemented.

MS IE/Firefox output example:

> An emergency lighting survey to be conducted. The emergency light
>   ing system is to inspected by a competent electrical engineer an
>   d any recommendations following such an inspection are to be imp
>   lemented.

Code used:

```
<div style="width: 100%; word-break:break-word">
    <p><?php echo $row['observation']; ?></p>
</div>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why would you use `work-break:break-word`?

Comment: Are there any styles in the P tag? like this I can't see the described effect.

Comment: remove the `word-break:break-word` and all will be good. The default behaviour on all browsers is NOT to break words.

Comment: Many thanks for a quick response in answer to you questions there are no styles in the P tag and the reason for using word break is that i was search for a solution to the problem and clutching at straws. I have now removed the word break and still no improvement and safari and chrome look the same as msie

Comment: I [cannot reproduce this](http://jsfiddle.net/tbDex/) in IE9 or FF. Can you extend the example so [it reproduces the issue](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Many thanks Jeroen I could not either on fiddle either I put it in a table with % instead of px. There must be a conflict somewhere else in the CSS i will investigate and come back

Comment: Problem solved. Following Jeroen's reproduction I looked further into the css and notice that the word-break:break-word was also in there. I commented this out and without the same within my div it is now working as expected. Again thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From [5.3. Breaking Rules for Letters: the ‘word-break’ property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break), there is no value `break-word`. You have however [6.2. Overflow Wrapping: the ‘word-wrap’/‘overflow-wrap’ property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap), which provides `break-word`

> Name:     overflow-wrap/word-wrap
>   Value:  normal | break-word
>   ...
>   ‘**break-word**’
>       An unbreakable "word" may be broken at an arbitrary point if there are no otherwise-acceptable break points in the line. Shaping characters are still shaped as if the word were not broken, and grapheme clusters must together stay as one unit. No hyphenation character is inserted at the break point.